# Configuring AspectJ aspects using Spring IoC with JavaConfig?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-java-config

According to Spring's Documentation [Configuring AspectJ aspects using Spring IoC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-configure) in order to configure an aspect for Spring IOC, the following has to be added to the xml configuration:

```
<bean id="profiler" class="com.xyz.profiler.Profiler"
      factory-method="aspectOf">
  <property name="profilingStrategy" ref="jamonProfilingStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

As suggested by @SotiriosDelimanolis, rewriting this as the following in JavaConfig should to work:

```
@Bean
public com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler() {
    com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler = com.xyz.profiler.Profiler.aspectOf();
    profiler.setProfilingStrategy(jamonProfilingStrategy()); // assuming you have a corresponding @Bean method for that bean
    return profiler;
}
```

However, this only seems to work if the `Profiler` aspect is written in native aspectj `.aj` syntax.  If it is written in Java and annotated with `@Aspect`, I get the following error message:

> The method aspectOf() is undefined for the type Profiler

Is there an equivalent way of writing this using JavaConfig for aspects written with @AspectJ syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that there is an `org.aspectj.lang.Aspects` class to provide for specifically this purpose.  It appears that the `aspectOf()` method is added by the LTW which is why it works fine in XML configuration, but not at compile time.

To get around this limitation, `org.aspectj.lang.Aspects` provides a `aspectOf()` method:

```
@Bean
public com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler() {
    com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler = Aspects.aspectOf(com.xyz.profiler.Profiler.class);
    profiler.setProfilingStrategy(jamonProfilingStrategy()); // assuming you have a corresponding @Bean method for that bean
    return profiler;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Where is this \@Bean defined? In the Config class? Do you still annotate your Advice with @Aspect and use \@EnableAspectJAutoProxy on Configuration class? I have tried this but it doesn't look like AspectJ compile-time weaving is kicking in. Here's my sample code: https://github.com/jigishpa/spring-samples/tree/master/aop/hello

Comment: I use spring java configuration with @EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED) and our aspects listed in the <aspects><aspect> section of the aop.xml. When we define the aspects beans with Aspects.aspectOf I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing storey.jeff.MyAspect: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: storey.jeff.MyAspect.aspectOf()

Which I believe means the aspect has not been woven before the bean creation. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an equivalent way of writing this using JavaConfig?

Almost always.

```
@Bean
public com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler() {
    com.xyz.profiler.Profiler profiler = com.xyz.profiler.Profiler.aspectOf();
    profiler.setProfilingStrategy(jamonProfilingStrategy()); // assuming you have a corresponding @Bean method for that bean
    return profiler;
}
```

The `factory-method` is explained in the documentation in [**Instantiation with a static factory method**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method).

Comment: I tried that but had a compile time error as `aspectOf()` is undefined.  "The method aspectOf() is undefined for the type Profiler".  I presumed I was doing it wrong.

Comment: @EricB. I don't know AspectJ well enough to help you there, but if you haven't provided an `aspectOf` method for your `Profiler` class and AspectJ hasn't provided it through other means (byte code manipulation), then there's not much you can do. The XML bean definition you have in your question is exactly equivalent to the `@Bean` method above. I'm going to assume that you're missing something from your AspectJ setup.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it may be related to the aspect being defined as an `@Aspect` and the Java compiler confusing it for a regular java class.  If I write the aspect as a `.aj` file, it seems to work as expected.  The problem is that I don't know how to resolve this issue.  I've updated my question to reflect the new info.

Comment: @EricB. I'm going to leave my answer because it answers `Is there an equivalent way of writing this using JavaConfig`, but your question should really be about configuring AspectJ with Spring, with which I cannot help :(.