# problems with Native AspectJ with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aspects

I am testing AspectJ compile time weaving with Spring 4 (once I get it to work, I want to use it in my projects). I have the following service class:

```
@Service
public class HelloService {

    public String sayHello(){       
        return sayHello2();
    }

    public String sayHello2(){
        return "Hello from AOP2!";
    }
}
```

And here's my AspectJ advice:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ExecutionTimeAdvice {

    @Around("execution(* com.senyume.aop.service..*(..))")
    public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        long duration = (endTime - startTime);

        logger.info("Method " + pjp.getSignature() + " took " + (duration/1000000.0) + " ms)");

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I am trying to enable AspectJ Compile time weaving according to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-configure). Since I am using annotations, I tried to follow advice mentioned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852657/configuring-aspectj-aspects-using-spring-ioc-with-javaconfig/22872161#comment42657547_22872161).

When I run the application, I don't see the advice being applied to sayHello2(). What am I missing? What am I doing wrong here?

Full source code [on github](https://github.com/jigishpa/spring-samples/tree/master/aop/hello)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gradle build uses the Java compiler to build the project. How about actually using the AspectJ compiler? That would help a lot if you want to use AspectJ. `;-)`

You can use the [Gradle AspectJ plugin](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj).

Comment: Thanks! It's my first project with AspectJ and I didn't realize that I would've to add/configure the compiler.

Comment: Reading some documentation before using a brandnew technology is always a good idea. :-)

Comment: I was following Spring documentation ... it wasn't clear that I needed to have additional compiler step in my build file.

Comment: Spring AOP is proxy-based and does not need an additional compiler. AspectJ is/does. In your thread title you mention "native AspectJ", so it should be clear that a Spring manual is not what you need but an AspectJ manual. I do not read an Emacs manual if I want to learn Vi, even though both are text editors. ;-)