# AspectJ and Springboot not working together

Tags: aspectj, spring-boot, load-time-weaving

In my project i want to use pure aspectj in combination with spring-boot
 While configuring the project we ran into some issues.

Found another [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075701/problems-with-native-aspectj-with-spring) but that doesnt help us.

This is what we did:

- got springboot project
- defined 2 aspects, 1 simple spring main class
- added aspectj plugin to gradle build
- set applicationDefaultJvmArgs to use the javaagent for aspectjweaver

Here is a link to our repo at github. https://github.com/svenhornberg/MDSD

and here is the Travis-CI build log https://travis-ci.org/svenhornberg/MDSD/builds

But it's still not working like it should.

Think i need some help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be trying to mix compile-time weaving and load-time weaving of your classes. You should chose one approach and use it consistently.

If you want to go with compile-time weaving, remove `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` from `Application` and update `build.gradle` to remove the configuration of `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`. There's other clean up that you could do, but these two changes should be sufficient to get your app up and running. With these changes in place, at startup I see it output:

```
1
Please use List instead of a concrete implementation for method: findByPrio.
[]
Please use List instead of a concrete implementation for method: returnTest.
You used a method with only one boolean parameter. Refactor it into 2 methods with True, False at the end.
true
```