# Why is Spring initialising my Aspect twice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a simple aspect that is doing some logic around one method. I am using Spring Boot with AspjectJ. For some reason, the constructor of the aspect is being invoked twice.

My aspect looks like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HandlerLoggingAspect {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandlerLoggingAspect.class);

  public HandlerLoggingAspect() {
    log.info("Initialising HandlerLoggingAspect");
  }

  @Around("execution (* io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder+.decode(*,*,*)) && args(ctx,byteBuf,outList)")
  public void interceptByteDecoding(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> outList) throws Throwable {
    setupMdcAroundJoinPoint(joinPoint, ctx);
  }

 //... rest of the code ...
}
```

The aspect runs fine around the methods I am expecting it to, but for some reason Spring Boot is initialising my aspect twice. The `Intialising HandlerLoggingAspect` message appears twice at start.

```
2016-09-25 18:36:26.041 [main] DEBUG  Running with Spring Boot v1.4.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.2.RELEASE
2016-09-25 18:36:26.041 [main] INFO   No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-25 18:36:29.891 [main] INFO   Initialising HandlerLoggingAspect
2016-09-25 18:36:29.892 [main] INFO   Initialising HandlerLoggingAspect
```

If I remove the `@Component` from the Aspect, it is not initialised at all.

My main class looks like this:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class Launcher implements CommandLineRunner {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Launcher.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
     //... logic performed by the class ...
  }
}
```

In case it makes any difference, this is my plugin configuration in my `pom.xml` for the AspectJ compile time weaving.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.8</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
        <org.aspectj.version>1.8.9</org.aspectj.version>

        <org.springframework.boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot.version>
    </properties>

...
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <proc>none</proc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <showWeaveInfo/>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <sources/>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

When I analysed the rest of the logs, it seems that only one of the instances is actually intercepting the pointcuts. So at least that is good.

What could be the reason for this double initialisation?

** **FURTHER INFO** **

It seems that in the Spring Documentation, there is something mentioned about Aspects being initialised twice.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying

However it says the following (I am using Spring 4.3.2):

> As of Spring 4.0, the constructor of your proxied object will NOT be
>   called twice anymore since the CGLIB proxy instance will be created
>   via Objenesis. Only if your JVM does not allow for constructor
>   bypassing, you might see double invocations and corresponding debug
>   log entries from Spring’s AOP support.

There is also written the following, and since I am using the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation this should apply too, so I know I am using CGLIB proxy:

> To be clear: using `proxy-target-class="true"` on
>   `<tx:annotation-driven/>`, `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` or `<aop:config/>`
>   elements will force the use of CGLIB proxies for all three of them.

I am using Java 1.8. Is there any known incompatibility between the combination of components I am using that is preventing the constructor bypassing mentioned above?

Comment: For starters try removing all annotations from your application but `@SpringBootApplication`. All the others are implied already and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is enabled by default (or you could add the `spring-boot-starter-aop` to have the correct dependencies. Also why are you using the aspectj plugin, that isn't needed as you are using proxies and not weaving.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I remove the `maven-aspectj-plugin` those two pointcuts of my `@Aspect` are not triggered. The classes I am intercepting are not Spring Managed beans. If I remove the other annotations and leave only `@SpringBootApplication` the effect is the same.

Comment: Then why even bother with `@Component` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. When using weaving you don't need that as that is only for proxy based AOP. With weaving you eliminate spring as the aspect becomes part of your compiled code already.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, tried it without the `@Component` and it solves the small issue I was having. Rather than getting initialised on startup (twice) the aspect is initialised on demand, and it only appears once. Not sure how would I go about it if I needed the aspect to be spring managed too though, while retaining the possibility of advicing non-spring managed classes.

Comment: I have never used Spring, but maybe you want to use `Aspects.aspectOf(..)` in your `@Bean` method in order to return an instance. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22872161/1082681) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I find expatiation on Spring Documents of Using AspectJ with Spring applications. As it said: "This ensures that Spring obtains the aspect instance by asking AspectJ for it rather than trying to create an instance itself.", and you can find examples from it:

```
<bean id="profiler" class="com.xyz.profiler.Profiler" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="profilingStrategy" ref="jamonProfilingStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another compiler, if you are using Ajc, change it to something else, from your IDE settings; It worked for me.