# Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference when use AspectJ and security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-aop, aspect

Hi i am developing a web application with using spring security and doing logging with AspectJ.

When i add new bean which is created with AspectJ getting this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingAspect': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

---

### My Spring configuration file ;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.org" } )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public LoggingAspect loggingAspect() {
    return new LoggingAspect();
}
```

---

### My Spring security configuration file with annotation;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { }
```

---

### Logging aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

/**
 * Default Constructor.
 */
public LoggingAspect() { 
}
```

I can't create this bean and couldn't find any solution.
May anyone help for this please.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but here is my guess: Try not to explicitly create a `@Bean` and see what happens if you let Spring do its magic. Maybe you are trying to create a singleton aspect for a second time which is already being or has already been created.

Comment: Another idea, maybe more promising: Use `Aspects.aspectOf(..)` in your `@Bean` method in order to return an instance. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22872161/1082681) for more details. If this works for you I can convert the comment into an answer so you can accept it later.